# Update a value in R using dplyr to subset rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I am wondering if it is possible to update a value of all the rows that fulfil some condition that I have selected using filter

I'm trying to get from here:

```
|Disaster     | TVal | FVal|
|-------------|------|-----|
|Tornado      | 0    | 0   |
|Fire         | 0    | 0   |
|Fire Tornado | 0    | 0   |
```

to here:

```
|Disaster     | TVal | FVal|
|-------------|------|-----|
|Tornado      | 1    | 0   |
|Fire         | 0    | 1   |
|Fire Tornado | 0.5  | 0.5 |
```

I'm selecting the rows like this

```
foo %>%  filter(grepl("TORNADO", Disaster))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the output a `base R` option would be to split the 'Disaster' column by white space, get the `unique` elements after `unlist`ing it ('un1'), then loop through the 'un1' (`sapply(..`)), use `grepl` to get the logical vector from the 'Disaster' column, divide the output by the row sums of the output (`addmargins` create the sum column) and assign the output to 2nd and 3rd columns of 'foo'

```
un1 <- unique(unlist(strsplit(foo$Disaster, "\\s+")))
m1 <- addmargins(sapply(un1, function(x) grepl(x, foo$Disaster)),2)
foo[2:3] <-  m1[,1:2]/m1[,3]
foo
#      Disaster TVal FVal
#1      Tornado  1.0  0.0
#2         Fire  0.0  1.0
#3 Fire Tornado  0.5  0.5
```

#### data

```
foo <- structure(list(Disaster = c("Tornado", "Fire", "Fire Tornado"
 ), TVal = c(0L, 0L, 0L), FVal = c(0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Disaster", 
"TVal", "FVal"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```